# I'm trying to deploy my django project to heroku. My app is not running the log shows error code 503

Tags: python, django, heroku, deployment

https://github.com/tony161293/hellodjango

This is my git repo link showing my sample code I'm trying to launch. The settings.py file was edited as per the documentation in Heroku django deployment. I'm trying to run my application. Is there any way to explicitly start my application after deployment?

Or any problem with the Procfile in the project..?

Answer (score 0):

Can you do the following:

`heroku logs --tail`, then run `heroku ps:restart` in a new window. Copy all the logs output, and paste it so we can help you debug!